# Beep sound when clicking on a button

Tags: android

I want to have a sound when im starting my game, I did this code in the oncreate :

```
SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    int iTmp = sp.load(getBaseContext(), R.raw.windows_8_notify, 1); // in 2nd param u have to pass your desire ringtone

    sp.play(iTmp, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

    MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.windows_8_notify); // in 2nd param u have to pass your desire ringtone
    //mPlayer.prepare();
    mPlayer.start();
```

how can I make my sound start again when it's ending? I mean replay the song..

Answer (score 1):

```
Add mPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

Take a look at [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping%28boolean%29)

Comment: thank you for the help! do you know where I can found music for my app? I don't want to put a real song, I want to put a background music like in Don't tap the white tile or in some other games..

Comment: Different questions should go to a different post.

Answer (score 0):

To start again the music, set loop to true:

```
SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

// in 2nd param u have to pass your desire ringtone
int iTmp = sp.load(getBaseContext(), R.raw.windows_8_notify, 1); 

sp.play(iTmp, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

// in 2nd param u have to pass your desire ringtone
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.windows_8_notify); 

// Here set loop to true

mPlayer.setLooping(true);

mPlayer.start();
```

Regards
PS

Comment: Thank you, its working :) do you know where I can found music for my app? I don't want to put a real song, I want to put a background music like in Don't tap the white tile or in some other games..